# Get list of files before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, upload

I got code for input file:

```
<input type='file'/>
```

When I selected a file from my directory, it shows file name beside choose button. Now, I'd to show all files that I choose. For example:

1.png

2.pdf

3.png

Note that (1, 2, 3 is file name)

How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a listener on the 'change' event of your input

Assuming your input id is 'inputFile'

```
document.getElementById('inputFile').addEventListener('change', onChange, false);

function onChange(e){
    var files = e.target.files;
    for (var i=0; i<files.length;i++)
         console.log(files[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use document.getElementById('inputfile').value;
For example:

```
<input id="inputfile" type='file'/>

<script>
var filename=document.getElementById('inputfile').value;


</script>
```

or if you use multiple  input use:

```
<input id="inputfile" multiple="multiple" type='file'/>

    <script>
filenames = new Array();
    for (var i=0; i<document.getElementById('inputfile').files.length; i++){
      filenames.push( document.getElementById('inputfile').files[i].name); 
     }


    </script>
```